# how can I connect to a http://localhost:4200 using browser which is a aws ec2

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I am learning node.js in an online course to build up a web server and app

before the teaching started, the teacher told me to set up your coding environment, and it got a direction to told me what to do step by step.

Because I using Chromebook, So I started an aws ec2 serve which is ubuntu 18.04 and using cloud9 for my ide

I installed node.js successful on the ec2

And the direction told me to type on those on the terminal

---

`git clone https://github.com/OpenClassrooms-Student-Center/5614116-front-end-app.git frontend`

You can then do the following:

```
cd frontend
npm install
ng serve
```

This will install all the dependencies needed by the front end app and will launch the development server.  Now, if you navigate to http://localhost:4200 , you should see the following (assuming you've followed the steps above successfully):

---

the direction say if I successfully followed the step, will see something on http://localhost:4200

On the terminal, at last show me

`ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.`

But how can I connect to http://localhost:4200 which was an ec2?

---

I tried using IP:4200, the browser keeps on loading the page and nothing shows up on the browser

－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－－

I found out that the program that teacher gave me to install set the URL to  http://localhost:4200

because cloud9 says the program was running, but  running at a URL call  http://localhost:4200

what should I do？

Answer (score 1):

Localhost refers to your local machine. But as mentionedd that your node.js running on ec2 and want to connect to it from your browser, get the IP of the ec2 and type in your browser- IP:4200
And it should work

Comment: I tried using  IP:4200, the browser keeps on loading the page
and nothing shows up on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem here is you have to add **port 4200** in your **aws ec2** instance **security group** to allow **inbound traffic**.

```
STEPS: 
1. Go to your EC2 instance.
2. Click security group from Description below.
3. Click Inbound then Edit.
4. Click Add Rule
5. Select Custom TCP , Port - 4200 , IP - 0.0.0.0/0
6. Then SAVE.
```

After that try `<EC2-IP:Port>` in your browser it will work fine.

Comment: I found out that the program that teacher gave me to install set the URL to  http://localhost:4200 

because cloud9 says the program was running, but  running at a URL call  http://localhost:4200 

what can I do?

Comment: Try changing your program to set the URL to <EC2-IP:PORT> for your web-server. You can check some config files to find the url configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**Opening Port in EC2**

1. Open EC2 Instance
2. Open Security Group Tab
3. Click on the link below `Security groups` label
4. Click on the `Edit inbound rules` button

**Add new Rule**

---

- Type -> Custom TCP
- Port Range -> 4200 (Whatever port your app runs on)
- Source -> Anywhere-IPv4

---

5. Click on `Save Rules` button
6. Open Firewall on your instance (in my case it's ubuntu)

`sudo ufw allow 4200/tcp`